# How to check one model is changed or not in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, model

I have a model in my HTML form. This model is a list of data and is ordered with its priority.

```
 rules = [ {"priority" : 1, "value" : "data 1"},
         {"priority" : 2, "value" : "data 2"} ];
```

I my UI I have provided the user can change the priority by move up and move down keys. While saving how can I check the model (list of rules) is change or not? Anyone please suggest one solution. 
If the model is changed, then rules will be

```
rules = [ {"priority" : 1, "value" : "data 2"},
          {"priority" : 2, "value" : "data 1"} ];
```

Then I need to save the changes, otherwise I need to avoid DB hits. How can I implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change array order in controller for priority change. just order them by priority in your template.

and make a deep watch on array. when something changes just mark a variable as "needToPostToServer"

```
$watch(array, function(){} ,true);
```

Edit: you can even stop watching after first change. so you could have some more performance